# Facebook redirect URI login product

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp

I've been including the "login with Facebook" product which allows you to get users information based on their Facebook's account email.

So when I try to redirect after the users accept my app on Facebook, it redirects to my homepage, not to the redirect URL I specified on the getLoginUrl() method.

My code is as follows:

```
$fb = new Facebook([
      'app_id' => "my app id",
      'app_secret' => "my secret",
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2'
      ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email'];

$loginUrl = $helper ->getLoginUrl('http://127.0.0.2/alumn-e/pages/facebookcallback/', $permissions);

$this->set('urlfacebook',$loginUrl);
```

These are my allowed redirection URIs:

[image]

For some reason my users are redirected to http://127.0.0.2/alumn-e/#_=_ when they accept the conditions on the use of my app, when I was expecting to get a redirection to http://127.0.0.2/alumn-e/pages/facebookcallback/.

I've been searching on google lots of time and I can't understand why.

EDIT: I've included error_reporting on my function and I've done the process of logging on fb and it doesn't show anything on the console.

Comment: 1) `$helper >getLoginUrl` it's missing an `-` . 2) `http://127.0.0.2/alumne/pages/facebookcallback/` doesn't have `alumn-e`  like the URIs you provided in the OAuth. However, you should enable `error_reporting` if not already.

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/6140684) for `error_reporting`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos 1) was a copy-paste mistake, sorry, I edited, 2) Could be that, I will check it tomorrow and I will tell you ! Thanks!

Comment: API v2.2 was shut down end of March. So start by initializing the SDK with at least v2.3.

Comment: @CBroe [Facebook login developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login) That example is wrong then?

Comment: Looks like it was not updated in that regard.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos the link mistake wasnt on my code because I use this: `$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(Configure::read('URL').'pages/facebookcallback/', $permissions);`, so that isnt my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this was a mistake on my facebook callback function so thanks to everyone! I finally understood this and I used v2.8 finally.